# CSS color to alpha for images?

Tags: css, image, html, transparency

Some weeks ago I remember to have seen on the web a page talking about being able to replace color areas of an image applying a color mask and making them transparent.

For example given an image of a logo over white, being able to turn white transparent by applying some new css property.

I can't find anything about it, maybe it was only a guy proposing some new ability for CSS3 or a vendor specific property.

I'm throwing this here just in case someone knows what i'm talking about and can give some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misreading your question first.

You could always try to load the image to html5 canvas, loop through the image and change the alpha channel to 0 or 255 based on the right combination of rg&b. Here's something to get you started: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/

Comment: Yeah, but i'm not interested in doing it using canvas. It's for a case were it would be cool to have it if browser supports it, but is not a big deal not to have transparent background where i'm trying to implement this. It was more for fun than any other thing.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I only found a way to add a opacity level in this [web](http://imagecss.com/opacity.html):

```
<img src="image.png" class="opacity30" />
```

> For this to work we must
>   add that class to our CSS file as well. It looks like this...

```
 .opacity30 { filter:alpha(opacity=30);
 -moz-opacity:0.3;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.3; opacity: 0.3; }
```

**EDIT1:**

I find this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Masks/Masks.html) that can be helpful to you. In that page teach to you how to add an image mask to an img tag.

Comment: This is neither what i'm looking for. The second link you provide is similar to what i'm asking, but based on color matching instead of alpha. I mean, when you apply a full white mask to the img, the white areas on the img will become transparent.

Comment: The OP asked aout how to convert a color to transparent one, not how to make the whole image transparent...